# Open.window() Document.referrer from HTTPS site to HTTP site empty

Tags: javascript, nginx, https, http-headers

Site1.com offers the possibility to open Site2.com in another window through a button. Site2.com checks document.referrer. As long as Site1.com and Site2.com are using HTTP everything works fine, and the referrer attribute contains the URL of Site1.com.

If Site1.com runs with SSL (https://site1.com), but Site2.com doesn't, the referrer is suddenly empty.

JS Client code on https://site1.com

```
window.open("http://site2.com", "mySite2.com")
```

The Site2.com checks the referrer in the JS client code by:

```
document.referrer
```

Which turns out to be empty.

**My Question**:
Is this a Javascript problem or an Nginx problem? Why is the referrer empty when using HTTPS on Site1.com ?

Again, if both sites are using HTTP, everything works just fine. The referrer just doesn't get passed on the Site2.com is Site1.com is using HTTPS.

Comment: pass it as a url get param

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. It is browsers security policy. They do not send referrer when go from secure site to non-secure.

Answer (score 3):

According to HTTP 1.1 protocol.

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure

[Here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3) is the policy.

You can not referrer on https to site using http. Referrer will get from

**https to https** 
or
 **http to https**.